# How to get a correlated subquery as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I dont know how I can do this sql query, probably its simple but I don't know how i can do it.

I have 2 tables:

```
Table_Articles:
COD   NAME
1     Bottle    
2     Car
3     Phone


Table_Articles_Registered
COD_ARTICLE   DATE
    1         05/11/2014
    1         06/11/2014
    1         07/11/2014
    2         08/11/2014
    2         09/11/2014
    3         05/11/2014
```

I want take in the table Table_Articles_Registered the row with the MAX date , finally I want get this result:

```
COD    NAME       DATE
1      Bottle     07/11/2014
2      Car        09/11/2014
3      Phone      05/11/2014
```

I need use the sencente like this. The problem its in the subquery. Later I use other inner join in the sentence, this is only a fragment.

```
select   
        _Article.Code,   
        _Article.Description ,   
        from Tbl_Articles as _Article left join     
        (   
            select top 1 * 
            from ArticlesRegisterds where DATE_REGISTERED <= '18/11/2014'   
            order by DATE_REGISTERED 
        ) 
        as regAux  
        on regAux.CODE_ARTICLE= _Article.CODE
```

I dont know how can I connect the field CODE_ARTICLE in the table ArticlesRegisterds with the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do this?:

```
SELECT
    Table_Articles.COD,
    Table_Articles.NAME,
    (
        SELECT MAX(Table_Articles_Registered.DATE) 
        FROM Table_Articles_Registered
        WHERE Table_Articles.COD_ARTICLE=Table_Articles.COD
    ) AS DATE
FROM
    Table_Articles
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a basic aggregation query with a `join`:

```
select a.cod, a.name, max(ar.date) as date
from Artiles a join
     ArticlesRegisterds ar
     on ar.cod_article = a.cod
group by a.cod, a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT TAR.COD_ARTICLE, TA.NAME, MAX(TAR.DATE)
FROM Table_Articles_Registered TAR JOIN
Table_Articles.TA ON TAR.COD_ARTICLE = TA.COD
GROUP BY TAR.COD_ARTICLE, TA.NAME;
```